# how to autoselect website language based on geolocation

Tags: html, ip-geolocation

I've just made a website in different languages. I don't want a language link on my page I just want to open the website with the right language based on where the user is located.
Basically if someone from China opens our page I want it to open in chinesse and not first in english, letting the user to decide which language should he choose.
Does anyone now how to achieve that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you considered basing the site language off of the browser language settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display website in a user's native language based on the IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630007/display-website-in-a-users-native-language-based-on-the-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

Do it using accepted languages of the browser rather than by geolocation.